# Check value is of the latest 5 ones

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `visitor_tokens` (
  `id` int(7) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `visitor` int(7) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `token` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE `visitor_tokens`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `visitor_tokens`
  MODIFY `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Now, I get a `token` and `visitor` from client.
I want to check if the `token` exists in the table (and belongs to `visitor`). Furthermore, this `token` must be of the 5 latest tokens of the `visitor` (indicated by `created_at` column).

This is my try:
`SELECT null FROM visitor_tokens WHERE visitor=? AND token=?`

Now my missing part is strict the `token` to be of the 5 latest tokens.
Meaning, if the `visitor`has 7 tokens (ordered ascending by `created_at`): `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]` And I want to check the visitor has the token `2` I wouldn't get `NULL`. For `3,4,5,6,7` I'd get `NULL`. (`NULL` meaning it did succeed to find the token in the given conditions). For visitor tokens: `[1,2,3]` I'd get `NULL` for all 3.

Comment: *the token to be of the 5 latest tokens* Select and count the tokens for provided visitor which are created not later then the provided token.

Comment: Whats wrong about `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM visitor_tokens WHERE visitor=? AND token=? ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 5` ? I may don't understand the question accordingly.

Comment: @O.M.N.L That count query will always return (at most) a single record, assuming that a given visitor/token combination can only occur once.  The order and limit logic does not do much.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Well, if the goal is to return no record then `SELECT IF(COUNT(id) < 1, id, null)` would do, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using analytic functions we can try:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY created_at DESC) rn
    FROM visitor_tokens
    WHERE visitor = 123
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE token = ? AND rn <= 5;
```

If the above select returns a record, then the token is valid according to your logic.

To show how the above is working with sample data, consider what the CTE would look like:

```
visitor | token | created_at | rn
123     | 7     | 2021-01-07 | 1
123     | 6     | 2021-01-06 | 2
123     | 5     | 2021-01-05 | 3
123     | 4     | 2021-01-04 | 4
123     | 3     | 2021-01-03 | 5
123     | 2     | 2021-01-02 | 6
123     | 1     | 2021-01-01 | 7
```

So, if we were searching for visitor `123` with token `4`, we would find a record, because token `4` is the 4th most recent token for that visitor.  On the other hand, searching for token `2` would return nothing, because it is not among the 5 most recent.